# Firebase Missing or Insufficient Permissions With Authenticated User

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Even though the user is authenticated, the create action is still causing an error:

```
Missing or Insufficient Permissions
```

Here's the Firestore rules I'm using:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
        // Sanitization of Request
      function recipeHasOnlyAllowedFields() {
        let requiredFields = [
            'name',
          'category',
          'directions',
          'publishDate',
          'ingredients'
        ];
        let keys = request.resource.data.keys();
        
        return keys.hasAll(requiredFields) && keys.hasOnly(requiredFields);
      }
      
      // Validation of Request
      function isRecipeValid() {
        let data = request.resource.data;
        
        return (
            data.name is string && data.name != '' &&
          data.category is string && data.category != '' &&
          data.directions is string && data.directions != '' &&
          data.publishDate is timestamp &&
          data.ingredients.size() > 0
        )
      }
    
      allow read: if true;
      
      allow create, update: if (
        request.auth != null &&
        recipeHasOnlyAllowedFields() &&
        isRecipeValid()
      );
      
      allow delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the data I'm sending:

```
{
  name: "Bread",
  category: "bakedGoods",
  directions: "Mix the ingredients together",
  ingredients: ["3 cups of flour", "1 cup of water"],
  publishDate: "01/01/2023" // pretend this is a timestamp
  isPublished: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue ended up being that `isPublished` was not an allowed field based on the custom rules for this store. Once that field was removed from the sent data (or added into the allowed fields), the create call worked again.

The error message feels like a red herring because it's a data issue, and not an authentication or authorization issue.

Hopefully there's a better way to validate the data with better error messaging in firebase.